# Model values is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to send some form values but they seems to be null. I can't figure out why. Im sure it's a simple solution or just something I've missed. 
Can someone please point me in the right direction.

```
@page
@model WebApp.Pages.LoginModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}
<h2>
    Logins
</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div style="border: solid 1px #ccc; padding: 30px 0 30px 30px; border-radius: 5px;
        width: 325px; margin: auto; display: table;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
                    <div style="height: 20px;">
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
                <div style="height: 20px;">
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
}
```

Here is my pagemodel

```
namespace WebApp.Pages
{
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter user name.")]
        [Display(Name = "User Name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter password.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }


        private SqlEntreprenörData<Entreprenör> _repository;

        public LoginModel(SqlEntreprenörData<Entreprenör> repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult OnPost()
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if(_repository.Login(UserName, Password))
                {

                   return RedirectToPage("/Admin/Avbokningar");
                }
            }
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my method that gets the user from the db. Here the username and password that is sent from the razorpage always null?

```
public bool Login(string username, string password)
{
   var user = (from userlist in _dbContext.Entreprenör
                where userlist.Namn == username && userlist.Password == password
                select new
                {
                    userlist.Id,
                    userlist.Namn
                }).ToList();
    if (user.FirstOrDefault() != null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
```

}

Comment: Try adding ```[BindProperty]``` annotation to your properties.

Comment: And, for your own good, you should remove all those `ö`, you may start getting weird errors at any point using characters like those

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto C# supports unicode, so people can write their code in whatever langauge (or emoticons) they like. It should be totally fine for someone from Finland to write code in Finnish if they want to.

Comment: @tigerswithguitars It *should* be. I've had some issues when some teammates used to write code in Spanish using accents

Comment: So your modelstate is valid, but the values are null?

Comment: Please post the **rendered HTML** of the ‘<form>‘ element’s opening tag.

Comment: try using a TextBoxFor instead of EditorFor element.

Comment: you are not returning the model to the view, thats why its null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[BindProperty]** attribute is used in Razor Pages to bind values from the page to PageModel properties.
Try the following changes

```
    [BindProperty]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter user name.")]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter password.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

From version 2.1 of ASP.NET Core, you can add the new **[BindProperties]** attribute to the PageModel class rather than applying **[BindPRoperty]** to individual properties, which results in all the public properties in the PageModel taking part in model binding:

```
[BindProperties]
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter user name.")]
    [Display(Name = "User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter password.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

Comment: this will help a little, but its not the answer